# Add an action filter dynamically to specific action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, actionfilterattribute

**several stories of one problem**

- I implemented a class (`MyClass`) which has a timeout callback thing, that should be start right after response dispatched to the client. I can use `action filter` to accomplish this, but i prefer not to use `action filter` explicitly (because of user convenience). instead attach the `Action Filter` when `MyClass` instantiated in the Action Method body.
- I have a situation which needs to fire a function delegate (used to track timeout thing) after action executed.
- Consider a class, designed to run some code (after `action method` executed) when an instance initiate on that `action method`.
- I need to execute some code after **one specific action** executed it's result (which i have it's action's name).

I know that using `custom Action Filter` and implement it's `OnActionExecuted` Method is the way to go, But what i'm trying to know is, how to attach that `action filter` **dynamically** while action is executing.
I mean, how to attach an `action filter` without subscribe it in `Global.asax` nor nominate it above the `Action Method` using `[MyCustomActionFilter]`.

---

**Edited:**

Consider i have following class:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public List<SomeDelegate> TimeoutCallbackFunction{get; set;}

  public MyClass()
  {
     // I want to attach action filter here.
     // user may forget to attach MyFilter filter to Action Method
     // So that it would be easier for users if this handled by MyClass Constructor.
     HttpContext.Current....... or something
  }
}
```

Consider my action filter is:

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
{      
    // Fetch newly added callback delegates from session.
    // Run them all.
}
```

so in the controller i have following code:

```
//I want following filter attach to be removed.
//[MyFilter]
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
   // This piece of code, should attach action method with 'MyFilter' filter
   // And dismiss user from nominate it above of 'MyAction' action method
   MyClass myObject=new MyClass();
}
```

by the way, by **"User"**, i mean the whom uses my class and develop an mvc.asp base on my dlls.

---

**my question is:**
*1-* Is it even possible to attach an `action filter` to the action that is currently executing? And if it is, how?
*2-* If it's not possible, then what other choice do i have to run some code right after `Result Executed`?
*3-* If there is no any alternative, so what people do in situation like this? is there any standardize way to fire a timer callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe action filters is not a good solution for your problem. However did you think about creating a simple flag somewhere and set it to true when you want to execute action filter functionality? For instance:

In your code you set the flag:

```
HttpContext.Current.Items["ExecuteMyActionFilter"] = true
```

And in your action filter:

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
{
    if ((bool?) HttpContext.Current.Items["ExecuteMyActionFilter"] == true)
    {
        // Execute your code
    }
}
```

You can use static variables, database or any state conditions to check if your action needs to be executed. Hope you got the idea!

Comment: @Rzassar still, the answer is the same. I don't see any better way.

Comment: the problem is, where should i attach filter to action? i mean how `OnActionExecuted` should get called (while i want to omit manually filter registration by user) and release user from this kind of complexity. i rather to force user to call [MyFilter] above it's desired action method than force user to turn a flag down or up.

Comment: by the way, by **"User"** i mean the whom uses my class and develop an mvc.asp base on my dlls.

Comment: Man you have to do something based on conditions, probably you shouldn't use action filters for your problem. This is my impression...

Comment: @ Andrei M you completely right. on the other hand as i mentioned "how to attach an action filter without subscribe it in Global.asax nor nominate it above the Action Method using [MyCustomActionFilter]". by that i meant, how to achievea functionality like `action filter >>> OnActionExecuted` without need to register it statically. now! do you thing is there another way to exec some code just before response dispatch to client?

Comment: I guess, in controller it should be fine